# Inserting a column in panda based on certain row key condition

Tags: python, pandas, insert

I am new to the pandas and python.  I want to insert a column from dataframe2 to into   dataframe1. However, my condition is, some of the rows are missing in dataframe2. So I would like to insert into only those rows where a row key matches and some null values into remaining rows in the new column. For example:
[DataFrameExamples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caXjA.jpg)

I have data frames with more than 50 K rows into each. Please let me know how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) functionality might be something that you are looking for. A left join can solve your problem. By default merge uses an inner join. You can change this behavior by passing a different how argument:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='key', right_on='key')
```

Comment: you can just use `on='Key'` , since both left on and right on keys are same. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would completely work out but you may try:
df['c2'] = a new series as null. Then

For all keys in Df1 if the key exists in df_2 update c2 in df1 for that key with the corresponding value.